# CCSequence not firing correctly

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a problem that I've never seen before with code that I wrote a couple years ago with cocos2d cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b.

Basically, all I'm trying to do is move Dominoes (CCNode SubClass) around on my screen.  Once a round is completed, the winner is determined and the dominoes are moved over to the right of the screen...or should be.

This is what happens 95% of the time when using non-64 bit devices.

[image: 7.1 95% of the time]

However, sometimes the following happens.  For some reason, one of the tiles does not get moved at all.

[image: 7.1 5% of the time]

Finally, when I'm using the 64-bit simulator, I get this

[image: 64-bit]

Here the tiles are being moved, but they aren't rotating.  I slowed down the duration to see if I could tell what was happening and it appeared to be firing 3 times.

Here is the code.  What am I doing wrong?  I've never had issues with this code until fairly recently.

```
-(void)determinetrickwinner: (NSArray *) table
{

    [self unscheduleAllSelectors];

...
    for (int i = 0; i <[table count]; ++i)
    {

        if (int_winningplayer==1)
        {
            pos_x=int_X1o+int_X1*i;
            pos_y=int_Y1o+(int_player1wincounter-1)*int_Y1;
        }

        if (int_winningplayer==2)
        {
            pos_x=int_X2o+int_X2*i+int_X1*3*1.08;
            pos_y=int_Y2o+(int_player2wincounter-1)*int_Y2;
        }

        if (int_winningplayer==3)
        {
            pos_x=int_X2o+int_X2*i+int_X1*6*1.08;
            pos_y=int_Y2o+(int_player3wincounter-1)*int_Y2;
        }

        Domino *temp_tile = table[i];
        temp_tile.scale=flt_scale;

        CCDelayTime *delay=[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.01f];

        CCMoveTo * translate = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.1f position:ccp(pos_x,pos_y)];
        CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.1f angle:90.f];
        CCSequence * rotSeq = [CCSequence actions:translate, delay, rotLeft, nil];
        [temp_tile runAction:rotSeq];

        NSLog(@"i=%d",i);

    }

        if (int_numberoftricks<7)
        {

            if (int_winningplayer==1)
            {
                str= player1;
                //boo_player1move=true;
                [self schedule: @selector(startPlayer1moves) interval:.25];

            }
            if (int_winningplayer==2)
            {
                str= player2;
                [self schedule: @selector(Player2Moves) interval:1.3];
            }
            if (int_winningplayer==3)
            {
                str=player3;
                [self schedule: @selector(Player3Moves) interval:1.3];

            }

            [currentplayer setString:str];
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you include arm64 in the supported/valid architectures build settings? If so, remove that. Cocos2d prior to v3.0 has lingering issues when compiled as 64-bit code. Still there's a possibility of a general incompatibility with 64-bit devices in cocos2d versions prior to v3 regardless of whether the code is built as 64-bit.

Comment: Other than that, log what is executing to find out if you are perhaps running the method multiple times.

Comment: I have NSLog(@"IN determinetrickwinner"); at the top of my code.  It only executes once.  NSLog(@"i=%d",i); Shows it's correctly running 3 times. I've been pulling my hair out over this one.  I'll try removing the arm64, but this won't solve my second problem?

Comment: Adding 64-bit solved the issue for 64-bit devices.  Is there any reason why this would also affect the other issue?  I've found it's a fairly difficult bug to debug since it only happens sporadically.

Comment: The most probably cause could be a float/double mismatch. A common issue I've observed when OS X went 64 bit was that the update: method was defined to take a CGFloat as input, which is double on 64 bit systems, but cocos2d is passing in a float parameter. Therefore the delta time was always 0 on 64 bit machines because the method signatures did not match (update:(float)dt vs update:(double)dt). There are other parts of the engine where such signature mismatches and floating point value truncations exist.